# Document Viewer for phonegap Applications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Have anyone used Childbrowsers or InAppBrowser plugin for pdf/anydoc viewer in android...IF so  how does it work..I need to develop a document viewer for my phonegap Application...Plz suggest something..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the provided documentation or tells us what you have tried

InAppBrowser is a built in plug-in for the standard phonegap release since version 2.3.0.
Childbrowser was used for version previous to that as a non default plug-in.

Documentation is on the phonegap website

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: clinton, i understand InAppBrowser is a built in plugin..for iOS apps, HTML5 object works fine to display any document but on android it fails, since android does not have a default pdf viewer..and plugin that i wrote takes pdf out of the application...i want it to be displayed on the same page...is there any way to do it...

Comment: the was a pdf bug in phonegap 2.3.0 try 2.5.0 the latest? are you using the latest?

Answer (score 0):

Andrdoid does not come with a default PDF viewer. So you may need to open your docs using google document reader and display in your InAppBrowser.

Comment: will that be displayed on the same page or it will take the pdf out of  the application? my concern here is, i want to display a document on the same page (inside a div tag)..how to do that ?

Comment: InAppBrowser will always get displayed on top of your app taking the entire screen. but it will be part of your app. when click the close button in the InAppBrowser, you go back to your app. You can try using PDF.JS(https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) to render the PDF inside your HTML using JavaScript. Its still a beta software, so use it carefully. For me, it could render most of my PDFs but not all.

Comment: yes..i just have implemented InAppBrowser and it works just the way u said. It might not be the option for me, is there a way to load local pdf's in it..for now i have a online pdf that gets loaded..which takes the entire screen

Comment: you can use the PDFViewer plugin to display local PDF: https://github.com/RandyMcMillan/CDVPDFViewer

Answer (score 0):

For everybody who is stuck with this problem here is what i´ve finally found out:

HTML 5 object tag: not working

Embedded tag: not working

childBrowser Plugin: I think it would work, but it is designed for the 2.0.0 version. So you´ll get a lot of errors so i didn´t get it to work.

Phonegap InAppViewer: If you use it like that:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/test.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes')
```

it wont work. The InAppViewer can´t open PDF, it doesn´t matter if the PDF is external or local stored.

My solutions so far (not what the actual idea was):

you can call the window function with _system. like that:

```
window.open('http://www.example.com/test.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes')
```

this will open the PDF in the normal Browser and download it. After downloading it will ask if it should open it with a PDF viewer. But you have to go back to your app and open it again after that.

Another possibility would be that you just download it to your sdcard with the Phonegap Filesystem API like that:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
"file://sdcard/ics-android.png",
function(entry) {
    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
},
function(error) {
    alert("download error source " + error.source);
    alert("download error target " + error.target);
    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
});
```

The last thing i´ve found out is, to use Google docs/drive to open it with the InAppViewer linked to google docs like that:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

window.open('https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.example.com/test.pdf&embedded=true', '_blank', 'location=yes'); 
ref = window.open('index.html', '_self');
 }
```

This will open the PDF in the app viewing it on google docs. You can generate your permalink here: https://docs.google.com/viewer So even if you change your pdf file, it will still work

I hope this summary will help you save time. If there is another solution let me know

Comment: how does one dismiss the google docs viewer and return to the app??